# Reading out Manipulate controls dynamically generated in a list

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, evaluation

I've been trying to dynamically generate Manipulate controls in a list, like so:

```
names = {"a", "b"};

Manipulate[
 Evaluate[c /@ Range[2]],
 Evaluate[Sequence @@ Table[
    {{c[i], 0, names[[i]]}, {0, 1}},
    {i, 2}
    ]]
 ]

(* {0, 0} or {0, 1} or {1, 0} or {1, 1} *)
```

This works fine, but things start to break when I actually try to use the value list generated from `c`, for example by changing the manipulated expression to

```
Pick[names, Evaluate[c /@ Range[2]], 1]

(* {} *)
```

or by assigning it to variable and then displaying it like

```
selList = Evaluate[c /@ Range[2]];
selList

(* {c[1], c[2]} *)
```

It doesn't seem to be properly evaluated; the manipulated values for `c[i]` don't get plugged in.

However, if I extract the values from `c` 'by hand' everything is fine again:

```
selList = {c[1], c[2]};
Pick[names, selList, 1]

(* {} or {a} or {b} or {a, b} *)
```

Am I missing something here? Thanks!

By the way, I'm using version 10.3.0.0 for macOS.

Comment: A shortcut: `Manipulate[
 selected,
 {{selected, {}, ""}, names, ControlType -> CheckboxBar}
 ]`.